# @RequestBody validation in spring 3.0.5

Tags: validation, rest, spring-mvc

I have a REST controller and am trying to ensure that the request body is truly of the type I think it will be.

For example:

```
@Controller
public class myController{

   @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value = "/addFoo", headers="...")
   public @ResponseBody String addFoo(@RequestBody Foo){
   ...code to add a new Foo
   }
}
```

Unfortunately someone could post a Bar object instead of a Foo object and I want to intercept that occurrence and return a sternly worded message about Barring my Foo -- instead of having Spring throw a mapping error and returning a 500 Internal Server Error.

What's the best way to handle this?
I'm using Spring 3.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the exception like this

```
@Controller
public class SimpleController {

  // other controller method omitted

  @ExceptionHandler(IOException.class)
  public String handleIOException(IOException ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
    return ClassUtils.getShortName(ex.getClass());
  }
}
```

or by defining a HandlerExceptionResolvers

both are documented here :

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to 3.0.x, I can suggest you to ugprade 3.1 which is finalized past month.

It is a newly added feature in Spring version 3.1. Please see [Validation For @RequestBody Method Arguments](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html#d0e1569)